# How to detect real-time change of text files?

Tags: c#, algorithm, logging

I am stating to write a little PC tool to read log files using c# or java. The log files will be in .txt format. An application is running and writing logs, and I want my tool to open the log at the same time and refresh automatically when a new line is written to the log file.

My challenge is, how do I detect the log file changes so that my tool will have real-time displaying ability? This is a general question but pseudo codes will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: grab some gnu source and look at the `tail` app, which does exactly what you want with the `-f` option.

Comment: The [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class might help.  Or you can set a timer and poll the length.

Comment: have you thought about using the FileWatcher Class
her is a good link for starters. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-net-filesystemwatcher-object-to-monitor-directory-changes-in-c/6165137

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `FileSystemWatcher` class ([MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher)). Be careful though, if you try to open the file while the other process is writing the file you will probably be denied access.

Comment: This saved me from doing some really sketchy things.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There's a bunch of this questions here, and answers too:

[Reading file content changes in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373090/reading-file-content-changes-in-net)

Your target is FileStream object, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I would poll the file and check it's metadata for the last changed date, or if you're using .NET, you could use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class