# Get the output log from wrapper service (OpenVPN)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, openvpn

I'm thinking of writing a simple custom .NET OpenVPN client.
I was wondering in what different ways would it be possible to get and display the output log of the underlying *openvpn* executable?

(Just for the information's sake - OpenVPN service is basically a wrapper for the main executable, created to simulate transparent background execution (e.g. like Linux daemon), as well as to bypass non-admin user issues. It is written in C. It picks up its start configuration params from the registry, as decribed on this page in the [Running OpenVPN as a Windows Service](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html) section.)

BTW, I was examining the clients like Viscosity and HMA, they are both .NET clients, and both have this feature for displaying the openvpn output log. HMA runs *openvpnserv.exe* (that is the service), and keeps the log file. Viscosity has its own service wrapper, and I didn't spot the log file on the file system (which doesn't mean it's not there somewhere)... so I can't really tell what's going on in this case.

One obvious solution is to track original log file for appended lines, e.g. [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373090/reading-file-content-changes-in-net), which seems to work. What would be my other options here, and should I at all consider anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, alternative (and probably desirable) solution is to use [OpenVPN Management Interface](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/management-interface.html) and its print log capability, simply by enabling it with one of the commands (depending on the desired effect):

```
log on     # turn real-time logging on
log all    # show cached log history
log on all # second + first
log 30     # show most recent 30 log-history lines
```